# Navigating to a different URL in a web browser control each time a button is pressed from another page

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone application where I have buttons on the mainpage. There is another page browser.xaml which has a web browser control. How do I assign URLs to the buttons on mainpage, so that each time any of them is being tapped, it navigates to browser.xaml and the webbrowser control will navigate to a certain URL? I'm avoiding creating web browser controls for each button.

Comment: are you using mvvm?? if yes which framework and have you written your own??

Comment: check my answer which uses navigationservice class to perform this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frist for For the button_Click event handler, add the following code:

```
  private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/browser.xaml?link=" + textBox1.Text, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and on browser.xaml create a function

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string linkurl= "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("link", out linkurl))

            textBlock1.Text = linkurl;


    }
```

for command parameter use this

```
   <Button Content="Parameterized Command" CommandParameter={Binding links} />
```

Comment: Thank you so much that's what I needed! Though I'm yet to try it out but I believe it's really gonna work with few tweaks. But there's something else, I've got lots of buttons on Mainpage. Should I declare their urls as strings or array and how do I do that?

Comment: please vote if this is helpfull...and you can associate link to the commandargument to the each button

Comment: You should use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` on the link before appending it to the URI. Otherwise, the parameters of the link might be truncated. And don't forget to call `HttpUtility.UrlDecode` when reading it back.